# cifs mount error(2): No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, mount, smb

I have a Buffalo Neworkstorage (NS) installed.

I am able to mount the NS from my Rock Pi N10 running Debian (buster) using the following command:

```
sudo mount.cifs //<<ip.address>>/SHARE /mnt/lspro
```

But on my PC running Ubuntu 18.04, using the exactly the same command as above, I got an error:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

The `dmesg` logs are:

```
[48381.426142] CIFS: Attempting to mount //10.1.10.77/share
[48381.426168] No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
[48381.440240] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

`/mnt/lspro` exists on the Ubuntu box. I can `cd /mnt/lspro` and `ls /mnt/lspro` it's confirmed it there!

I can even mount the NS through Files other location by "smb://<ip.address>" using Anonymous without password, but I cannot `mount.cifs` in the Ubuntu box.

Does anyone have the same situation and found a solution?

Comment: Also, the `--verbose` of mount.cifs might provide enough useful info for diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issues and needed to install package `keyutils`

Answer (score 2):

after reading dmesg as suggested by @A.B,

```
[48381.426142] CIFS: Attempting to mount //10.1.10.77/share
[48381.426168] No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
[48381.440240] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

and found the solution for my situation on ubuntu box by adding `-o vers=1.0`:

```
sudo mount.cifs //<<ip.address>>/SHARE /mnt/lspro , -o vers=1.0
```

Thank you for all your helps! ;))

P.S. per A.B's comment below, it is preferred to use higher SMB version for security reason. For my NS box, the highest version I can go is 2.0. So the solution update for my situation is:

```
sudo mount.cifs //<<ip.address>>/SHARE /mnt/lspro , -o vers=2.0
```

Comment: "version 1.0 is not recommended": is this version subjected by the Network Storage box support? if my NS box only support version 1.0 (Buffalo LS220D688 just bought it yesterday, I would assume it supports the latest smb version ?!), then I probably cannot do anything, is that right?

Comment: just check my Buffalo NS box, on SMB support: SMB Protocol:Switch between SMB2 and SMB1 automatically. I tried set -o vers=2.0 and it works. But not 2.1 nor 3.0.Would 2.0 secure enough? or has to be 2.1 and above?

Comment: Can't tell but 2.0 probably better than 1.0

Comment: Found this random link: https://www.buffalotech.com/knowledge-base/windows-10-cannot-access-shares-on-nas . "All current Buffalo NAS units support SMB version 2 at a minimum, and the TS3010 and TS5010 series support SMB version 3"

Comment: That helps! Thanks a lot.